# I am trying to use google location picker and it is always showing RESULT_OK == -1

Tags: android, google-maps, google-location-services

My code

Called location picker by using this code

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(Checkout.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Milla.log('e',"locationpickerE1",e.getMessage()+"");
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Milla.log('e',"locationpickerE2",e.getMessage()+"");
        } 
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST=11290;
```

Add trying to get location details using this code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Milla.log('i',"onActivityResult","iscalled "+PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST+" "+RESULT_OK);

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

                Log.i("locationpicker",selectedPlace.getAddress()+"  "+selectedPlace.getLatLng().longitude+"  "+selectedPlace.getLatLng().latitude);
                // Do something with the place
            }else {
                Log.e("locationpicker","not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

But always it is showing  `I/onActivityResult: iscalled 11290 -1`
And i checked permission  and there is no issue.
What is the problem ?     
It is working and it allow to select location but nothing found in activity

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <permission
        android:name="rs.fon.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="rs.fon.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You log like this `Milla.log('i',"onActivityResult","iscalled "+PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST+" "+RESULT_OK);`

change to `Milla.log('i',"onActivityResult","iscalled "+requestCode+" "+resultCode);`
for check correct values..

after log if the **requestCode** not equal to **11290** and  **resultCode** not equal to **-1**

that is a main problem..

I think you are using **PlacePicker** in fragment

if i'm right then just change this line

`startActivityForResult(builder.build(Checkout.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);`

to

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(builder.build(Checkout.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Comment: I am not calling  it from frg

Comment: I am calling it from activity

Comment: @Midhilaj change the `Milla.log` according to answer than check whats the log values??

Comment: Milla.log('i',"onActivityResult","iscalled "+resultCode+" "+PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST+" "+RESULT_OK);

Comment: I/onActivityResult: iscalled -1 11290 -1

Comment: @Midhilaj also check 'requestCode' in log.